# what is the different between "urge" and "craving"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

"Smokers often start the habit in their teens. During puberty, the urge to fit in is enormous."
Can I change "the urge to fit in is enormous." into “the craving for fitting in is enormous."

Comment: You can. But I wouldn’t.

Answer (score 2):

One of the things that sets the tone apart in both versions is the direction in which the desire is coming from.

An *urge* can come from an outside pressure:

> A: I urge you to seek help for that alcohol problem of yours.

Whereas a *craving* is completely internal:

> B: But I can't help it if all I do is crave it when I'm not drinking it.

Note how you cannot interchange the words in both of these.

An urge doesn't necessarily have to be inflicted by someone else:

> I have an urge to scratch this bug bite because it itches so much.

Think on the above. The desire to scratch is coming from the feeling of itch from the bite.

> I just crave relief, I don't want to itch anymore.

Here, the craving is internal, not necessarily being forced by the itch itself.